# Yii2 kartik/date/datepicker shows wrong format while update

Tags: php, date, datepicker, yii2, active-form

I use kartik DatePicker in my activeform.

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
```

My activeform field:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'transferred_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                        'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select date ...'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                            'todayHighlight' => true
                        ]
    ])->label('Transferred Date');
?>
```

While **creat**ing I save it as a UTC date format :

```
$model->transferred_date = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($postModel['transferred_date'])*1000);
```

When I **update**, it shows as

[image]

I need this as

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide the formatted date to the widget.

- When using `ActiveForm` you can override `afterFind()` for the specific model to format the date and override the default timestamp value for the `transferred_date` field.
- For Formatting, you can use the [yii-i18n-formatter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter) component by defining inside the config file `common/config/main.php` if using `advanced-app`, or `config/web.php` if using `basic-app`.

  Add below in the config file

  ```
    'components'=>[
        'formatter' => [
            'dateFormat'=>'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'datetimeFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
        ],
    ]
  ```

  Add below into your model

  ```
    public function afterFind() {
        parent::afterFind();
        $this->transferred_date=Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->transferred_date);
    }
  ```

Now change the field definition to below and refresh the page

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'transferred_date')->widget(DatePicker::class, [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'todayHighlight' => true,
    ],
])->label('Transferred Date');
```

Comment: Helpful one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your date like so:

```
'value' => $model->isNewRecord ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+2 days')) : date('d-m-Y', strtotime($model->transferred_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

ok my friend all you need is to change the format of your date picker widget in your active form to be like the following

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'transferred_date')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
                        'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select date ...'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'format' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                            'todayHighlight' => true
                        ]
    ])->label('Transferred Date');
?>
```